# Is there something more effective than ladder networks for semi-supervised learning?

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning

The paper Semi-Supervised Learning with Ladder Networks by Rasmus is famous and interesting but a bit old now.

Did researchers find any better option for semi-supervised learning ? For example, what is the current state the art for MNIST with only 100 labels?

Comment: One recent work is this: Learning Neural Random Fields with Inclusive Auxiliary Generators (https://openreview.net/pdf?id=Syzn9i05Ym). It includes experiment with 100 labels you mention. Some additional works are related to GAN, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.06548.pdf (Triangle-GAN) https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.01541.pdf (CT-GAN) You might also want to check out this experimental unification of recent methods: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.09170.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Numerous works have come forward after Ladder Networks. The most recent and state of the art as of March 29, 2020 is [Fixmatch](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.07685).

Recent approaches are making use of new data augmentation techniques like RandAugment, AutoAugment, Cutout, Mixup, CutMix, etc. as well as formulate the problem in the following ways:

1. **Consistency-training**
   Train model such that it predicts the same label for both original and augmented versions of an unlabelled image. Example: [Unsupervised Data Augmentation](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.12848)
2. **Self-training**
   Train model on labeled data, predict on unlabelled data and combine confident labels along with the labeled examples to train a new model. Rinse and repeat). Example: [Noisy Student](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.04252)
3. **Combined Approaches**
   Combine both the above approaches along with a combination of augmentation techniques. Example: FixMatch

You can view the papers after Ladder Network organized by month and year [here](https://github.com/amitness/awesome-semi-supervised-learning).